# Display a view from another controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, controllers

Is it possible to display a view from another controller?

Say for example I have a `CategoriesController` and a `Category/NotFound.aspx` view. While in the `CategoriesController`, I can easly return `View("NotFound")`.

Now say I have a `ProductsController` and an action and view to add a product. However, this action requires that we have a Category to add the Product to. For example, `Products/Add/?catid=10`.

If I am not able to find the Category based on `catid`, I want to show the `NotFound` view from the Categories controller instead of creating a `CategoryNotFound` view under the Products controller.

Is this possible or am I structuring things in the wrong way? Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 329, accepted):

Yes.  By default, ASP.NET MVC checks first in `\Views\[Controller_Dir]\`, but after that, if it doesn't find the view, it checks in `\Views\Shared`.

The shared directory is there specifically to share Views across multiple controllers. Just add your View to the Shared subdirectory and you're good to go.

If you do `return View("~/Views/Wherever/SomeDir/MyView.aspx")` You can return any View you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like the solution I should be using.

I still wonder if it is possible to display a View from another controller though.  I'm guessing this violates some rule in MVC?

Comment: In the situation you describe above, yes, you should be using the Shared folder.

Comment: Yep, that is also possible.  If you do 

return View("~/Views/Wherever/SomeDir/MyView.aspx")

You can return any View you'd like.  This doesn't violate any particular rule per se, however, ASP.Net MVC is all about "convention over congfiguration".  In other words, the framework is built to operate automatically using certain conventions, and you should utilize it where possible.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination.  I didn't know Views could be called like that.  The Shared directory of course works perfectly :)

Comment: I wasn't in a Controller, so I had to use `new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Views/Error/Unauthorised.cshtml" };` and it worked

Comment: This solution leaves the URL unchanged (the view which will be rendered  won't correspond to the displayed URL in the browser)!

Answer (score 174):

You can use:

```
return View("../Category/NotFound", model);
```

It was tested in ASP.NET MVC 3, but should also work in ASP.NET MVC 2.

Comment: Works in MVC 2, and turned out to be the cleanest solution for an unusual situation I'm dealing with.

Comment: Resharper will report that link as an error but it still works.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyKing - Resharper 7 (in VS2012) correctly identifies a path that is formatted as `"~/Views/Category/NotFound.cshtml"`.

Comment: Worth noting: this solution works with display modes, e.g. if you had a "/Category/NotFound.Mobile.cshtml" view.

Answer (score 77):

Yes its possible.
Return a `RedirectToAction()` method like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionOrViewName", "ControllerName");
```

Comment: I believe this should go as RedirectToAction("ActionOrView", "Controller", null) as otherwise second paramater is routeValues

Comment: But in this case, you have to actually write the action in the controller, unlike with the View solution.

Comment: @tobbenb3 That's a much better solution as opposed to hardcoding a result. Either way you shouldn't be passing in a path string.

Answer (score 35):

Have you tried `RedirectToAction`?

Comment: I would say that this is the MVC for anyone that doesn't want the view int he shared folders, note that for all other solutions (such as using direct paths) anyone trying to re-factor the views will not have to take in mind that it is also being used in another controller, resulting in unpredictable behavior

Comment: how about without redirecting?

Comment: way better solution than moving the view to shared folders

Comment: This solution requires action on controller, View(directPath) renders output without any action. When you add an action, you need to think to hide it from direct access via url, it will generate step in browser history etc. But yes, it's my way to go.

Comment: RedirectToAction sends a 302 response code to the browser. That is not appropriate when you are trying to show a 404 not found page. That is, this solution appears to work but will confuse search engines.

Comment: Couldn't you modify the Response.StatusCode to the proper status code in the view? Or would the status code be read by the search engine before this modification take place?

Comment: @NightOwl888 good point about the 404.  I'm not sure if he would want a 404 status though since he has a page for it.  Although, its an interesting point.  I would say if the categories are dynamic then maybe 404 is not a good idea?  This maybe like having a 404 if you searched for keywords that yielded no results.

Comment: @NullReff - No, each request only returns a single HTTP response. In the case of `RedirectToAction`, the first request will return a 302, instructing the browser to do a *second* request for the URL (strictly speaking, the browser doesn't have to follow this instruction, it is out of your control). If a search engine *does* follow a 302 redirect to a 404 not found response, this is a confusing set of instructions, and a wasteful and unnecessary round trip.

Comment: @PaulJohnson - There would really be nothing wrong with displaying a custom page and also providing a 404 status code. The HTTP status and the page that is displayed are independent. However, making the status 302 when you meant to provide a 404 is a wasteful approach. If you want your application to show a 404 for a certain URL, you should *route* to that action, not *redirect* there. That is, make one round trip, not two.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, you can. Return an Action like this :

```
return RedirectToAction("View", "Name of Controller");
```

An example:

```
return RedirectToAction("Details/" + id.ToString(), "FullTimeEmployees");
```

This approach will call the GET method

Also you could pass values to action like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Details/" + id.ToString(), "FullTimeEmployees", new {id = id.ToString(), viewtype = "extended" });
```

Comment: how would i send an object with this approach?

Comment: Take a look @Djeroen

Comment: You are not returning a view, you are calling an action.

Answer (score 5):

You can also call any controller from [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)/[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). Say you have a controller returning 404 or some other usercontrol/page. Then, on some action, from your client code, you can call some address that will fire your controller and return the result in [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) format
your client code can take this returned result and put it wherever you want in you your page...

Comment: I did not know that.  That sounds like it's something I might use in the future.  Yes, mvc rocks :)

Answer (score 1):

With this code you can obtain any controller:

```
var controller = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ControllerB>();
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(this.Request.RequestContext, 
controller);
```

Comment: Translation: With this code you can obtain any controller: [code], Regards,

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.