# ViewResult and lookup directories

Tags: asp.net, viewresult

```
new ViewResult() { ViewName = "Error_403" };
```

in this case .net looks through current controller view directory (~/Views/Home/) and in shared (~/Views/Shared/)

Is there any way to point to specific directory right here `ViewName = @"Errors\Error_403"`?
Or may be any other simple solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
   New ViewResult(){ViewName="~/Views/SomeDir/Error_403.aspx"};
```

See here for a similar issue: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879852/asp-net-mvc-display-a-view-from-another-controller)