# MVC Calling a view from a different controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My project structure is like:

- Controllers/ArticlesController.cs
- Controllers/CommentsController.cs
- Views/Articles/Read.aspx

Read.aspx takes a parameter say "output", which is the details of the article by id and its comments, passed from `ArticlesController.cs`

Now I want to write then read the comment:: `write()` & `Read()` funct in `CommentsController.cs`

For reading the article with its comments, I want to call `Views/Articles/Read.aspx` from `CommentsController.cs` by passing output parameter from `CommentsController.cs`

How can I do this?

### **UPDATE**

Code Here:

```
public class CommentsController : AppController
{
    public ActionResult write()
    {
        //some code
        commentRepository.Add(comment);
        commentRepository.Save();

        //works fine till here, Data saved in db
        return RedirectToAction("Read", new { article = comment.article_id });
    }

    public ActionResult Read(int article)
    {   
        ArticleRepository ar = new ArticleRepository();
        var output = ar.Find(article);

        //Now I want to redirect to Articles/Read.aspx with output parameter.
        return View("Articles/Read", new { article = comment.article_id });
    }
}

public class ArticlesController : AppController
{   
    public ActionResult Read(int article)
    {
        var output = articleRepository.Find(article);

        //This Displays article data in Articles/Read.aspx
        return View(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be so much easier to follow if you displayed the controllers code with both actions that you want to work with.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't understand your question. From `ArticlesController` you want to call a method at `CommentsController`. Is that it?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To directly answer your question if you want to return a view that belongs to another controller you simply have to specify the name of the view and its folder name.

```
public class CommentsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        return View("../Articles/Index", model );
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ArticlesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        return View();
    }
}
```

Also, you're talking about using a read and write method from one controller in another. I think you should directly access those methods through a model rather than calling into another controller as the other controller probably returns html.

Comment: I am Sry for Poorly written question as I am new to .NET . I have updated my ques with code for your ref.

Comment: `[InvalidOperationException: The view &#39;Articles/Index&#39; or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.` I tried this. It looked in /Comments/Articles/Index. Perhaps this is a result of using areas. `return View("../Articles/Index")` worked.

Comment: If you're using areas than yes this will not work. Why are you using two different controllers in different areas to access the same view?

Comment: I am not using Area's in my application and still     return View("../Articles/Index") worked

Comment: You can also start at the root and work the other way if you choose `~/Views/Articles/Index.cshtml`

Answer (score 2):

You can move you read.aspx view to Shared folder. It is standard way in such circumstances

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if I got your question right. Maybe something like

```
public class CommentsController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult WriteComment(CommentModel comment)
    {
        // Do the basic model validation and other stuff
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid )
            {
                 // Insert the model to database like:
                 db.Comments.Add(comment);
                 db.SaveChanges();

                 // Pass the comment's article id to the read action
                 return RedirectToAction("Read", "Articles", new {id = comment.ArticleID});
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
             throw e;
        }
        // Something went wrong
        return View(comment);

    }
}


public class ArticlesController : Controller
{
    // id is the id of the article
    public ActionResult Read(int id)
    {
        // Get the article from database by id
        var model = db.Articles.Find(id);
        // Return the view
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: ThankYou...After clicking submit button on write comment form,In debugging my control goes to read.aspx with all valid values but for some reason it is not getting rendered.Where as on writing an article the same Read() function renders read.aspx page properly.

Comment: So Now, In dubugging my control is going till read.aspx but it is not getting displayed..Still write_Comment form is displayed

Comment: The article is found from the database in the read action when you redirect from WriteComment? Does your Read action return the proper model with updated comment?

Comment: public class ArticlesController : AppController
   {   
     public ActionResult Read(int article)
      {
 var output = articleRepository.Find(article);
 return View(output);
      }

}

Comment: Yes it returns a proper output and return view(output) takes the control to Read.aspx but it is not displayed.

Comment: So are you saying if you put a breakpoint to `return RedirectToAction("Read", "Articles", new {id = comment.ArticleID});` it's not getting hit but returns `return View(comment);` instead? If that's the case then the validation fails or some exception is hit. See the updated answer and check if the method caughts an exception. If everything goes smoothly then there must be something wrong with your view.

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Read", "Articles", new {id = comment.ArticleID});    is getting hit and control moves from CommentController.cs to ArticlesController.cs's Read action just like it happens in normal read                                            My comment form is using Ajax.BeginForm()..I think the prob is something related to it

Answer (score 0):

It is explained pretty well here: [Display a view from another controller in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879852/display-a-view-from-another-controller-in-asp-net-mvc/879862#879862)

To quote **@Womp**:
By default, ASP.NET MVC checks first in `\Views\[Controller_Dir]\`,
but after that, if it doesn't find the view, it checks in `\Views\Shared`.

ASP MVC's idea is "convention over configuration" which means moving the view to the shared folder is the way to go in such cases.