# Orchard routing rule

Tags: routes, orchardcms

How this can be "translated" to Orchard

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Durandal App Views",
    url: "App/views/{viewName}.cshtml",
    defaults: new { controller = "DurandalView", action = "Get" }
);
```

I tried to make theme based on [this](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2014/03/durandaljs-enable-razor-views.html).

It is not working and breaks all Orchard site

```
    public class Routes : IRouteProvider {
    public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes) {
        foreach (var routeDescriptor in GetRoutes())
            routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
    }

    public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
    {
        return new[] {
            new RouteDescriptor {
                Priority = 5,
                Route = new Route(
                    "/App/views/{viewName}.cshmtl",
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "Durandal"},
                        {"controller", "DurandalView"},
                        {"action", "Get"}
                    },
                    new RouteValueDictionary(),
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "Durandal"}
                    },
                    new MvcRouteHandler())
            }
        };
    }
}`
```

Comment: How does it not work, and how is it breaking the site?

Comment: Could you show us your controller too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like, you are creating your Controller in a Theme. 
Why dont you try to build it as a module first.
 
Going through some tutorials will not harm as Orchard powerful extensibility capabilities take a bit to tune in to. 
[Orchard Tutorials](http://docs.orchardproject.net/)
Having said that,...
1. Create a Module
2. Add your Routing
3. Create your Get Action
4. Get your View under the Module's `Views` folder, probably in a folder called `DurandalView`  like the controller.

Then you're left with calling the view.  Why don't you just try `return View(viewName);` 
 You could also have a look at this related question on how to call diferent views [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879852/display-a-view-from-another-controller-in-asp-net-mvc). There, you will be able to see why your ~/App/Views.. will never work. or will not work with the actual folder structure.

Comment: Yes I don't know why but when I made it as module it works?!!

Comment: You might need to read on MVC (convention over configuration?), also Themes are not meant for that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you look at this

```
Route = new Route("/App/views/{viewName}.cshmtl", ....
```

Your View filename is followed by `.cshmtl` when it should be `.cshtml` 

Try changing the filetype, that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is controller code as requested

```
[Themed]
public class DurandalViewController : Controller
{
    private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;
    private readonly IWorkContextAccessor _workContextAccessor;
    public DurandalViewController(IContentManager contentManager, IWorkContextAccessor workContextAccessor, IShapeFactory shapeFactory, IOrchardServices services)
    {
        _contentManager = contentManager;
        _workContextAccessor = workContextAccessor;
        Shape = shapeFactory;
        Services = services;
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    dynamic Shape { get; set; }
    public IOrchardServices Services { get; private set; }
    public Localizer T { get; set; }


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(string viewName)
    {
        return View("~/App/views/" + viewName + ".cshtml");
    }

    //public ActionResult Display(int id)
    //{
    //    var contentItem = _contentManager.Get(id, VersionOptions.Published);
    //    dynamic model = _contentManager.BuildDisplay(contentItem);
    //    var ctx = _workContextAccessor.GetContext();
    //    ctx.Layout.Metadata.Alternates.Add("Layout_Null");
    //    return new ShapeResult(this, model);
    //}
}
```

Orchard alias module enabled

request to http://`localhost`:30321/OrchardLocal/Themes/Durandal/App/views/shell.cshtml gives 404 and no Controller has been invoked

It brakes Orchard at all when priority is set to 100 as exmp

Comment: Is your controller in the Theme?. the tilde will always work until 'http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/' in any .NET project. so you are missing 'Themes/Durandal/'. that is, if that works. Ive never tried to call a View in a controller from a Theme before.

Answer (score 0):

@ErMasca 
this was copy-paste error 
actually code is right - .cshtml

```
new RouteDescriptor {
                Priority = -15,
                Route = new Route(
                    "/App/views/{viewName}.cshtml",
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "Durandal"},
                        {"controller", "DurandalView"},
                        {"action", "Get"}
                    },
                    new RouteValueDictionary(),
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "Durandal"}
                    },
                    new MvcRouteHandler())
            }
```