# Render Another Controllers View From Within a Controller (Not Partial View)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ruby-on-rails-3

We are in the process of converting a Ruby on Rails 3.2 App to .NET MVC 4 using C# as the language. Is there a way to render a view from another controller within the current controller in C# similar to the way Rails does.

For example, in Rails, in your current controller you can call:

```
render :template => 'another_controller/action'
```

When searching online all I could find were articles/SO questions regarding rendering ***partial*** views from a C# controller. Is rendering a full view from another controller considered not best practice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display a view from another controller in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879852/display-a-view-from-another-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Pass it the action name and the controller name, each as a string.