# How to Properly Initialize a Shared View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core

After implementing [this useful response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/879862/35142) and moving my `Login` view to the `Shared` views folder, it isn't getting initialized when I call it from another controller.

My calling code:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddressCorrectionList()
{
    if (ValidateSecurityToken()) // ensures the app server thinks we're still logged in
    {
        [deleted for clarity]
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Login", new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = "/Report/AddressCorrectionList" });
    }
}
```

Action in AccountController being called:

```
[ActionName("Login"), HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult LoginGet(LoginViewModel model)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = model.ReturnUrl;  // I set a breakpoint here.

    if (model.ReturnUrl != null)
    {
        model.InfoMessage = "Please login to access " + ResourceNameFor(model.ReturnUrl);
    }

    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(model);
}
```

If I directly follow a link to the login page, it works fine. My breakpoint in `LoginGet` is called.

If I try to follow a link to a page that requires a login but I am not logged in, it works fine. I am correctly redirected to the Login page. My breakpoint in `LoginGet` is called.

The problem arises when I call the `View` from another controller, such as from the first of the two code snippets. The login page is displayed, however my breakpoint from `LoginGet` is not called, and my `ReturnUrl` is not set.

`ValidateSecurityToken` exists because although the application may consider the user to be logged in, a separate app server to which I make API calls, may log the user out due to its own timeout rules.

How do I fix my call from `AddressCorrectionList` so my view is properly initialized?

Comment: Maybe some clarity would help.  So are you calling the shared Login view as a partial view from the parent view?  If not, how are you rendering it?

Comment: It's not a partial view. It's just a "normal" `.cshtml` view that used to live in the `Views/Account` directory and is rendered, presumably, within the `RenderBody()` call within `_Layout.cshtml`. (Methinks I'm missing the essence of what you're trying to ask me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `return View("viewName", model)` that cshtml file is directly rendered with the given model. The **action** `LoginGet` is never hit as you call a method to return a *view* instead.

What you are looking for is to execute the `RedirectToAction("LoginGet")` method, or any of it's overloads.

Comment: You put me on the right path, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10785274/35142) completed the picture. For my case, the correct use was `RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", model );`